# How to Use SVG or Vector Drawables in Flutter SDK

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

I want to use SVG/Vector Graphics in my Flutter Application.
is there any library or Dart Package which can be used?

Answer (score 6):

**steps**

1. use this plugin **flutter_svg**
   https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_svg
2. adding images to Assets
3. import and adding this widget

```dart
SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/Defect/icon${values[index].childId}.svg', height: 50.0,),
```

Answer (score 2):

To display the SVG from Assets in Flutter.

1. Add the following code in pubspec.yaml file under dependencies
   `flutter_svg: ^0.22.0`
2. Add the following code in the header of your main.dart
   `import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';`
3. Assign the SVG to one variable like `final String assetName = 'assets/images/avatar.svg';`
4. `new SvgPicture.Asset(assetName, height:100, width:100,)`

Comment: Sadly flutter_svg is extremly limited. Most SVG taken out of the box will actually not work.